# Divination on a bard

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, bard

Suppose a bard uses *Magical Secrets* to take the spell [Divination](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/divination):

> Your magic and an offering put you in contact with a god or a god's servants. You ask a single question concerning a specific goal, event, or activity to occur within 7 days

Who or what being would they be asking? If they are a believer in a god then I assume the given god, however, how/who would an agnostic/atheist type bard contact?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast yes, why?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast i was just asking as a pc because it seemed interesting and i wanted to know if there was a raw answer

Comment: @KorvinStarmast yes, i wasn't looking for a god, just seeing if there was a mechanical requirement to be dedicated to a god such as the case with clerics

Comment: OK, then Thomas seems to have covered it. I'll remove all of these comments.

Answer (score 5):

#### It's up to the DM.

One of the frequent criticisms of the Bard's *Magical Secrets* feature is that it gives the Bard access to spells that are flavored uniquely for other classes. This is one such example. Almost every cleric has a god of some sort, so they usually ask the god they have favor with, "What's up?"

That said, *there isn't actually a restriction on what god is contacted with divination*. It appears as though the caster may choose (or the DM may choose):

> Your magic and an offering put you in contact with a god or a god's servants.

It just says "a god or a god's servant", so the DM decides if the player chooses or if the DM chooses.

#### This is probably a poor choice for Magical Secrets.

Since *divination* is a 4th level spell, it cannot be taken until 10th level, when you could also be choosing a 5th level spell, such as *commune*:

> You contact your deity or a divine proxy and ask up to three questions that can be answered with a yes or no. You must ask your questions before the spell ends. You receive a correct answer for each question.

This one gets you three questions instead of one.

Comment: I'd say it's also up to the player in this particular case.

Comment: My mouse is horrible today. Hit the DV not UV button. And I noted a couple of typos, so I did a slight edit.  And fixed my spaz.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say *divination* is a worse choice than *commune*, as they serve slightly different purposes- *divination* can get you answers more elaborate than yes/no, and can also be used in a pinch with a casting time of 1 action if there's something you're about to immediately do that you wish to ask about. (Plus the lower level spell slot if casting non-ritually)